# Maquetación extra pequeña en Bootstrap se rompe

Tags: css, bootstrap, bootstrap-4, responsive, framework

Estoy realizando un layout para practicar con la grilla de Bootstrap, sucede que para dispositivos mas allá de 576px todo bien, ocurre cuando es menos que eso que realmente se pone todo en una sola fila alguien me podría explicar como solucionarlo, ya intente colocar col-12 pero no funciona todo se pone en una sola fila.

Quiero que quede todo como cuando esta en <576px pero no he podido.

[image: Acá es cuando se modifica la resolución a 575]
Acá es cuando se modifica la dimensión y se rompe
[image: Como puedo arreglarlo?]

Comment: Dentro de un **row** tienes que contar 12 columnas. Tal como lo estas haciendo, con el col-sm-12 estas forzando el salto a la siguiente linea del siguiente col-sm-12, pues ya ocupas las 12 columnas.  En el caso del col-md-6 lo que haces es que te quepan dos columnas seguidas (6+6=12) y luego vuelta a empezar con las 12 columnas en la siguiente linea.  Sabiendo eso planteate de nuevo el numero de columnas a usar tanto para el col-sm como para el col-md para que tengan la disposición que buscas en cada resolución.

Comment: Y cuando es menor del tamaño de sm veo que coge el valor **col** que divide todo lo que pongas en el row en partes iguales, y por eso te sale asi.  Para resoluciones más pequeñas puedes usar col-xs.. en este enlace tienes las resoluciones soportadas para cada prefijo del grid: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/layout/grid/#grid-options

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda, logre solucionarlo :)

Answer (score 0):

Dentro de BS4 no existe la clase `col` es por eso que no la toma en cuenta
En su lugar, agrega el breakpoint `xs`

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Bootstrap 4 Layout](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/overview/)

Comment: Si que existe **col** : https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#grid-options  pero lo del xs no se entiende demasiado bien

Comment: Probé con col, col-12 y col-xs-12 pero ninguna me ha funcionado :(

Comment: Si tienes el `container`? Revisa tu CSS yo hice esa prueba sólo importando BS4 y funcionó.

Comment: Muchas gracias ya logre solucionarlo, si tengo el container, gracias por tu ayuda!

Comment: @StevenLópez si esto te resolvió la duda, márcalo como aceptado. Si encontraste tú la solución, ponla como respuesta abajo!